# Modify filenames in a list of files and add them as a new column

Tags: r, lapply

I have an issue about adding new column for each element of list which will contain modified name of these files. So far, I am able to `substr` for creating filenames column but on the other hand I was not able to add new strings to this column such as "best" or "worst" words.

Here is my reproducible attempt,

This part for only producing .txt files to the working directory!

```
writeFiles <- function(n, maxRows=10){
  lapply(seq(10,90,10),function(x) write.table(sample(sample(maxRows)[1],replace=F),paste(x,'.txt',sep=""), quote=FALSE, col.names = FALSE,row.names=FALSE))
}    
writeFiles(9,10)

filesToProcess <- dir(pattern = "*\\.txt")

"10.txt" "20.txt" "30.txt" "40.txt" "50.txt" "60.txt" "70.txt" "80.txt" "90.txt"
```

In the next step I will read this files and modify filenames column that only takes first character of the .txt files.

```
data.list  <-  lapply(filesToProcess,function(x){
  tmp <- read.table(file=x, header = F,fill=T, comment.char='*')
#  tmp$filenames <- paste0(substr(x,1,1),c("best","worst"),sep="")
  tmp$filenames <- substr(x,1,1)

  return(tmp)
})

     data.list
        [[1]]
          V1 filenames
        1  4         1
        2  3         1
        3  7         1
        4  8         1
        5  1         1
        6  2         1
        7  6         1
        8  5         1

        [[2]]
          V1 filenames
        1  4         2
        2  1         2
        3  5         2
        4  3         2
        5  2         2
        6  6         2
        7  7         2

        [[3]]
          V1 filenames
        1  1         3
        2  3         3
        3  2         3
```

etc.

Indeed, I also want to new character strings to `filenames` column and I tried paste command inside of `lapply`,

```
 data.list  <-  lapply(filesToProcess,function(x){
  tmp <- read.table(file=x, header = F,fill=T, comment.char='*')
  tmp$filenames <- paste0(rep(c("best","worst"),c(4,5)),substr(x,1,1),sep="")
    return(tmp)
})
```

## Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "filenames", value = c("best1", #"best1",  :   replacement has 9 rows, data has 8

So the first 4 .txt files are marked as best and remaining 5 files are the worst .txt files.

How can do that inside of `lapply`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can subset first four elements of 'data.list', loop through them, and `transform` the 'filenames' column.

```
data.list[1:4] <- lapply(data.list[1:4], transform, filenames= paste0("best", filenames))
```

Similarly, the same can be done with the remaining 5 `list` elements

```
data.list[5:9] <- lapply(data.list[5:9], transform, filenames= paste0("worst", filenames))
```

---

We can also do this from 'filesToProcess' by creating a `vector` of 'best', 'worst' and then loop through the sequence of 'filesToProcess'

```
v1 <- rep(c("best", "worst"), c(4, 5))
lapply(seq_along(filesToProcess),function(i){
    tmp <- read.table(file=filesToProcess[i], header = FALSE, fill=TRUE, comment.char='*')
    tmp$filenames <- paste0(v1[i], substr(filesToProcess[i],1,1), sep="")
    tmp
  })
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. Can we do that without going outside of the loop? like I propose.

Comment: @Alexander I modified the code, please check if that works